# Facebook locations limit trying add locations giving an error message

Tags: facebook

We currently have 170 locations. We were approved for locations then we added 103 from a csv file. When we tried to add the rest it stopped at about 150 then gave an error every time we tried to add more. Is there a limit of how many locations you can have ? How do we solve this problem if we attempt to add them all and it stops halfway ? Is there A way to open a support ticket ? If the process stops halfway could be a business disaster for us. Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, because it does not seem to be a programming question. For Facebook end user support, please consult their Help section. Ways to report broken features can be found in there.

Comment: You may be correct. The thing is it is very difficult to get Facebook support and WizKid it was on her a lot is very nice and extremely helpful so I was hoping to get some kind of response